# Ordering codes over different occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the following done. Hereby a small snippet of data that I'm talking about. We have a Person who can have different codes on different dates.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (PersonId INT, CDate DATE, Code VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(2345,'20161010','V1'),(2345,'20170104','V2'),(2345,'20170320','V3'),(2345,'20170612','V4'),
(2421,'20161005','UNS'),(2421,'20161102','V1'),(2421,'20170118','V2'),(2421,'20170418','V3'),
(2421,'20170712','V4'),(2421,'20171004','V5'),(2421,'20171220','V6'),(2421,'20180113','LFM'),
(2421,'20180321','V7'),(2421,'20180822','V8'),(2421,'20190220','V9'),(2421,'20190315','EOT'),
(2430,'20161020','V1'),(2430,'20170116','V2'),(2430,'20170413','V3'),(2430,'20170726','EOT'),
(3004,'20161110','V1'),(3004,'20170131','V2'),(3004,'20170425','V3'),(3004,'20170503','LFM'),
(3004,'20170512','LFM'),(3004,'20170718','V4'),(3004,'20170725','LFM'),(3004,'20171010','V5'),
(3004,'20180102','V6'),(3004,'20180108','LFM'),(3004,'20180115','LFM'),(3004,'20180125','UNS'),
(3004,'20180328','V7'),(3004,'20180406','LFM'),(3004,'20180911','V8'),(3004,'20190227','V9'),
(3004,'20190306','LFM'),(3004,'20190313','UNS'),
(31740,'20190514','V1')
```

The result we are looking for is the following. I've added the PersonId's to the right as extra info so you can see which ones should be counted. The codes in the final result should be in sequence of the CDate over all the different persons. The code EOT should be the last.

```
RowNr   Code    Total   |
========================|
1       UNS     1       |   2421
2       V1      5       |   2345,2421,2430,3004,31740
3       V2      4       |   2345,2421,2430,3004
4       V3      4       |   2345,2421,2430,3004
5       LFM     1       |   3004
6       LFM     1       |   3004
7       V4      3       |   2345,2421,3004
8       LFM     1       |   3004 
9       V5      2       |   2421,3004
10      V6      2       |   2421,3004
11      LFM     2       |   2421,3004
12      LFM     1       |   3004
13      UNS     1       |   3004
14      V7      2       |   2421,3004
15      LFM     1       |   3004
16      V8      2       |   2421,3004
17      V9      2       |   2421,3004
18      LFM     1       |   3004
19      UNS     1       |   3004
20      EOT     2       |   2421,2430
```

Anyone who could give a starting point or helping us on how to achieve this?

Comment: why rows 1,13 and 19 not clubbed together in expected result and why are the personid's clubbed together in row 2?

Comment: You would need `LISTAGG()/GROUP_CONCAT()` functionality, that is available in SQL Server 2018. Alternatively you could use the `XML_` manipulation, but it's ugly.

Comment: @Deepshikha: row 2 : all persons have a V1; row 1: this UNS is referencing to an UNS code before V1 and this happens only with person 2421; row 19: this UNS is coming after V9 and only for person 3004;

Comment: You need to give a more detailed explanation on how you're grouping people. I've tried several "logical" options but keep getting different groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xml path` structure within `stuff()` function for version 2012

```
select
       row_number() over( order by code) RowNr,
       code, count(*) as total,
       stuff ((select ',' +  cast(p2.PersonId as varchar)
                 from
                 (
                  select code, PersonId,
                     row_number() over(partition by PersonId, code order by code) rn,
                     row_number() over(partition by PersonId order by code) rnk   
                    from @t
                  ) p2 
          where p2.code = p1.code
            and p2.rn = 1
          group by p2.PersonId, rn, rnk
          order by rnk
          for xml path('') ), 1,1,'') as comma_sep_string
from @t p1
group by code;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=23996d47f1f95d2d878ed1ad49a3aaa6)</kbd>

*but notice that the sample data and desired results are not compatible.*

Comment: Hi Barbaros, the result is actually what we want as output. Some more details. row 2 : all persons have a V1; row 1: this UNS is referencing to an UNS code before V1 and this happens only with person 2421; row 19: this UNS is coming after V9 and only for person 3004;